# RavenDB ESENT Initial storage size

Tags: initialization, size, ravendb, esent

Anybody knows if there is an option to set the RavenDB's storage initial size for the ESENT?
For VORON it should be, according to [this](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/java/server/configuration/configuration-options) site - Raven/Voron/InitialSize.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few settings that control this:

- `Raven/Esent/DbExtensionSize` - By how much the db will grow, and its initial size.
- `Raven/Esent/LogFileSize` - The size of the transaction logs

Comment: Shouldn't it be splitted into two config parameters, like:</br>
DbInitialSize

Comment: That is how Esent itself handles that, we just expose the value